# No se muestra mas de un boton en Datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

estoy realizando una practica en asp.net mvc pero el tengo un problema al mostrar los botones clásicos de editar y eliminar en un datatable.
Estuve revisando unos códigos, y encontré este en la pagina de la documentación.

basicamente es esto:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

         


            var Tabla = $("#usuariosTabla").DataTable(
                {
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Usuarios/GetList",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        
                        { "data": "NombreUsuario" },
                        { "data": "ApellidoUsuario" },
                        { "data": "CorreoElectronico" },
                        { "data": "Contrasenia" },
                        { "data": null }
                    ],
                    "columnDefs":
                        [
                            
                            {
                                "data": null,
                                "defaultContent": "<button>Delete</button>",                                
                                "targets": -1
                            }

                        ]
                });


            $("#usuariosTabla tbody").on('click', 'button', function () {
                var data = Tabla.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
                alert(data[0] + "'s salary is: " + data[5]);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Que el resultado es este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si quiero mostrar un segundo boton de eliminar. solo duplique el siguiente codigo.

```
"columns": [

                        { "data": "NombreUsuario" },
                        { "data": "ApellidoUsuario" },
                        { "data": "CorreoElectronico" },
                        { "data": "Contrasenia" },
                        { "data": null },
                        { "data": null }
                    ],

"columnDefs":
                        [

                            {
                                "data": null,
                                "defaultContent": "<button>Delete</button>",                                
                                "targets": -1
                            },
{
                                "data": null,
                                "defaultContent": "<button>Edit</button>",                                
                                "targets": -1
                            }

                    ]
```

al abrir el navegador me indica el siguiente error en la consola.

```
n[q] is undefined datatable
```

Alguna idea de como agregar un segundo boton? o alguien que me oriente.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes definir los botones en el mismo objeto:

```
"defaultContent": "<button class=\"delete\">Delete</button><button class=\"edit\">Edit</button>"
```